# What is the best practice to have a class of single object in Realm?

Tags: realm

For example, I need to store info for current user of the app and I would like that info to stored in Realm (similarly to usersdefault, but with some big files). Is it the same as just create a current user singleton in Realm? What is the best practice to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just create a single user object, or have an `isActive` property on your user class.

Doing `[User allObjectsInRealm:realm].firstObject` should then let you fetch the user (presuming you go the single user object route).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a faster way to access this single user other than the regular query that returns a RLMResults? What is the example line of code?

Comment: Edited my answer, and that query should be plenty fast!

Comment: What if object does not exist in database?

Comment: Then the method will return `null`